# How do I extract surnames with spaces in them as 'one' name/'en bloc'?

Tags: stata, spaces, names

Could anyone please advise on a way to extract surnames that have spaces in them, as a single block of names?

I have names in a dataset that look like this

```
clear
input str40 name
"R. P. de la Espriella Guerrero"          
"J. de Carvalho Ponce"                 
"E. De Freitas Drumond"                
"R. de la Fuente and M. E. Medina-Mora"
"C. Van Heyningen and I. D. Watson"
"A. Z. van de Wiel and D. W. de Lange"
end
```

I only want the first surname (so only the first author and excluding other authors) but I want those names that have spaces to be extracted 'en bloc'. So, ultimately resulting in a dataset as follows, for instance:

```
clear
input str40 name
"de la Espriella Guerrero"          
"de Carvalho Ponce"                 
"De Freitas Drumond"               
"de la Fuente"
"Van Heyningen"
"van de Wiel"
end
```

I'd be grateful for any help.

Comment: How do you decide if `and` is part of the name or not?

Comment: thanks @bew. this is part of the difficulty unfortunately. All 'and's are followed by a space and then another name starting with a first name abbreviation in capitals (e.g.  and D. W. de Lange)

Comment: the multiname particles can also be in capital e.g. De, Du etc

Comment: You start by defining rules that will select the text you want to delete and the text you want to retain. Then code to implement these rules can be suggested. You leave the rules to our imagination. It seems to me the rules you want to appy are, "first, delete everything from ' and ' onward" and "second, delete everything from the start to the rightmost period and the space following it". What remains is the first surname. That appears to work for your six samples, but whether it will work for your entire dataset is not something we can judge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is code that implements the two rules given in my comment above. It assumes the version of Stata used supports the unicode character string functions.

```
clear
input str40 name
"R. P. de la Espriella Guerrero"          
"J. de Carvalho Ponce"                 
"E. De Freitas Drumond"                
"R. de la Fuente and M. E. Medina-Mora"
"C. Van Heyningen and I. D. Watson"
"A. Z. van de Wiel and D. W. de Lange"
end
generate surname = name
replace surname = usubstr(surname,1,ustrpos(surname+" and "," and ")-1)
list, clean noobs
replace surname = usubstr(surname,ustrrpos(surname,". ")+1,.)
list, clean noobs
```

Comment: Thanks. Seems to do the job. Just noticed that the second usubstr produces a space before the surname. So i've amended this slightly to `replace surname = usubstr(surname,ustrrpos(surname,". ")+2,.)`.

It's not entirely clear to me why this happens as the starting position has already been specified as ". " (i.e. the fullstop with a space/blank). Does ustrrpos treat ". " and "." as the same?

Comment: also, for education sake, pls could you inform what the `.` does in the second usubstr?

i.e. in `usubstr(s, n1, n2)`, what does `n2==.` do?

Comment: Good catch. Indeed `ustrrpos(surname,". ")` returns the position of the first character in `". "` so adding 1 instead of 2 was an oversight on my part. For your second question, I encourage you to review the output of `help usubstr()` - Stata's online help should be the first stop for questions like this, so this response is meant to encourage you to become more familiar with it.

Comment: a note: the solution only works for 1-2 authored papers. For multiple authors, a step to remove non-first authors need to take place: e.g.   

    `replace surname = usubstr(surname,1,ustrpos(surname+" and "," and ")-1)`  

    `list, clean noobs`  

    `replace surname = usubstr(surname,1,ustrpos(surname+", ",", ")-1)`  

    `list, clean noobs`  

    `replace surname = usubstr(surname,ustrrpos(surname,". ")+1,.)`  

    `list, clean noobs`